# Count number of objects whose attribute are "null" or contain "null"

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON. From there I'd like to count how many objects I have which type attribute is either "null" or has an array that contains the value "null". In the following example, the answer would be two. Note that the JSON could also be deeply nested.

```
{
  "A": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "B": {
    "type": "null"
  },
  "C": {
    "type": [
      "null",
      "string"
    ]
  }
}
```

I came up with the following, but obviously this doesn't work since it misses the arrays. Any hints how to solve this?

`jq '[..|select(.type?=="null")] | length'`

Answer (score 2):

This answer focuses on efficiency, straightforwardness, and generality.

In brief, the following jq program produces 2 for the given example.

```
  def count(s): reduce s as $x (0; .+1);

  def hasValue($value):
    has("type") and 
      (.type | . == $value or (type == "array" and any(. == $value)));

  count(.. | objects | select(hasValue("null")))
```

---

Notice that using this approach, it would be easy to count the number of objects having `null` or `"null"`:

```
count(.. | objects | select(hasValue("null") or hasValue(null)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. For arrays you could use `IN`. I also used `objects`, `strings` and `arrays` which are shortcuts to a `select` of the according types.

```bash
jq '[.. | objects.type | select(strings == "null", IN(arrays[]; "null"))] | length'
```

```json
2
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vP_TN4NRIDN)

---

On larger structures you could also improve performance by not creating that array of which you would only calculate the length, but by instead just iterating over the matching items (e.g. using `reduce`) and counting on the go.

```bash
jq 'reduce (.. | objects.type | select(strings == "null", IN(arrays[]; "null"))) as $_ (0; .+1)'
```

```json
2
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/uLX6eX2masF)

Comment: @ikegami According to the [repository](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq), `IN` is defined as `def IN(src; s): any(src == s; .);`, thus purely `any`. (The lookup table is constructed by `INDEX`)

Comment: oh oops, yeah, mixed up IN and INDEX